# python https server post

Tags: python, https, server

I am trying to comeup with a http server which replies for a POST request from the client. The python code is returning http code 000 instead of 200/100. Plz let me know if there is any issue in the code

## CURL request returns 000 instead of 200/100

curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w "%{http_code}" -X POST https://10.1.4.179:443/xml  -k
000

## CODE:

```
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl
import logging

class GetHandler (SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

        def do_GET(self):
                logging.error(self.headers)
                SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

        def do_POST(self):
                self.wfile.write("<html><body><h1>POST!</h1></body></html>")

Handler= GetHandler

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
httpd=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("10.1.4.179", 443), Handler)
httpd.socket =ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, certfile='/tftpboot/server.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try sending the reponse code in your POST code section:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl
import logging

class GetHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

        def do_GET(self):
            logging.error(self.headers)
            SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

        def do_POST(self):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.data_string = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length']))

            data = b'<html><body><h1>POST!</h1></body></html>'
            self.wfile.write(bytes(data))
            return

Handler=GetHandler

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
httpd=HTTPServer(("localhost", 8080), Handler)
#httpd.socket =ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, certfile='/tftpboot/server.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I made a call to `curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/` and the response is

```
<html><body><h1>POST!</h1></body></html>
```

Only thing is I made the request over HTTP and hence commented out the line that load the certs.

Comment: I have tried doing send_response(200) it does not help. Also same result without xml. Just to be clear, I do get the response xml reply "<html><body><h1>POST!</h1></body></html>" . But the problem is status is always 000.  You could cut and paste and try urself.

Comment: PLZ let me know if somebody could help here.                      @ply26 did u get the choose to try your answers? did it work for you?

Comment: @dd76 Please check it now. I have updated the code and its working perfectly for me.

Comment: HI Piy26, Thank you so much. First thing its not about the o/p. Even the initial code provides me the required o/p. But the http status it returns was 0, instead of 200. That is my problem. If you could try the below curl, "curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w "%{http_code}" -X POST https://10.1.4.179:443/xml -k". Also I am looking for server supporting SSL connection and not pure HTTP